# C++ Template function returning type based on template arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'd like to create function that creates different types of generators (own classes) and I go with something like this:

```
template <typename Iterator>
class Generator {
Iterator begin_;
Iterator end_;
public:
Generator(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
    : begin_(begin)
    , end_(end)
    {}
};

template <typename GeneratorType, typename ContainerIterator>
GeneratorType<ContainerIterator> make_generator(ContainerIterator begin, ContainerIterator end){ // Error occurs here
    return GeneratorType<ContainerIterator>(std::forward<ContainerIterator>(begin), std::forward<ContainerIterator>(end));
}
```

But it's not compiling since error:

```
error: 'GeneratorType' is not a template (in line GeneratorType<ContainerIterator> make_generator...)
```

Do anyone know if it is possible and if yes how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `make_generator`'s definition

```
template <template<class> class GeneratorType, typename ContainerIterator>
GeneratorType<ContainerIterator> make_generator(ContainerIterator begin, ContainerIterator end)
```

You can pass templates as parameters to other templates. But the parameter definition needs to be specified as expecting a template template-parameter.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, `GeneratorType` is a type, not a template. You need to make it a template template parameter using the `template <typename> class` syntax:

```
template <template <typename> class GeneratorType, typename ContainerIterator>
GeneratorType<ContainerIterator> 
make_generator(ContainerIterator begin, ContainerIterator end){
    return GeneratorType<ContainerIterator>
             (std::forward<ContainerIterator>(begin),
              std::forward<ContainerIterator>(end));
}
```